# Is there a move-efficient way to rotate the center pieces on the Octo-Star?

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm to rotate the center column of the Octo-Star puzzle 45 degrees.

[image: Octo-Star]

The situation below occurs when four properly-oriented edges are next to each other, allowing for full freedom of movement.

[image: Octo-Star face]

As can clearly be seen, if the pieces highlighted in green are rotated 45° clockwise, the face is effectively solved. On this puzzle, you often want to rotate the centerpieces 45°, but the algorithm I currently have for doing so is slow.

With `[face]` representing a 45° turn, it is: `X = R2' D2 R2; [X U' X' U']4`

This algorithm takes 32 moves to complete, and I execute it frequently.

Is there a faster way to rotate these pieces?

Comment: er.... green? It's aqua.

Comment: No, the green star outline, not the aqua faces.

Comment: @Enigma: Was that edit really necessary?

Comment: @Deusovi He probably want to give it more attention without using a Bounty?

Comment: @Deusovi there is a badge that has to do with edits of very old posts ;)